# How to call mypageradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() from another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My app has the next structure, I have the Mainactivity where I have my viewPager. Inside this viewpager I add new fragment Activities. These Fragment Activities have a TextView with their names, I have created a OnlongClickListener in the textview so that when you OnlongClick in the textview the fragment Activity gets removed from the list in the viewpager I have in the main Activity.

I've tried to use in the fragment Activity the next code :

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();

but the result is an empty space in the position where the deleted fragment was.

I think the solution would be calling mypageradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the fragment Activity but the thing is that the viewPager and the pagerAdapter are created in the mainActivity and I want to notify the changes in the fragment activity.

**How can I call mypageradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() from the fragment activity?**

In this moment I have a solution for this problem but I don't think this solution is the best one, when I delete the fragment I create an intent for the mainActivity and then I StartActivity(intent). In the mainActivity onStart method I call mypageradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and then the empty spaces dissapear and the fragment list is sorted correctly. This solution is really slow and rough.

I would appreciate a better solution for my problem.

P.D: For help I have MyPagerAdapter class inside the mainActivity.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObservable.html

Comment: sorry should be ContentResolver.registerContentObserver() and notifyChange()

Comment: @pskink I don't know how to implement this in my code to solve my problem. I would appreciate some guides on how to use this.

Comment: call registerContentObserver in one place and later on call notify change in other place